# Two line-plots with the same color in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am quiet new to `plotly` and usually use `matplotlib`. However, I have to use `plotly` this time (due to `dash`). What I want is very simple with `matplotlib`, but I don't get it working with `plotly`: Two lines in the same figure that have the same color.

With `matplotlib`, this would look as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0, 1, 2, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3], color='black')
ax.plot([0, 1, 2, 4], [10, 9, 8, 7], color='black')
```

However, I have a hard time controlling the color in `plotly`. How do I get the above result with `plotly`? I have tried a kind-of workaround, which gives me two lines with the same color, but not the color I want (which is black):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1, 2, 4], 'y1': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'y2': [10, 9, 8, 7]})
fig = px.line(df, x='x', y=['y1', 'y2'], color=np.ones(len(df))
```

The result should look something like this:

[image]

I understand that it is normally "bad practice" to use the same color for two lines. However, in this specific case it is not; I want to plot some self-defined boundaries that function as a reference for other data that is to be added to the figure.

EXTRA: These lines should not be included in the legend. However, I want to plot 2D data in between these lines for which I would like to use some color-coding. This color-coding is preferably in the legend/added as a colorbar.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **plotly express** by default assigns color from color sequence for each trace
- there are two traces in your figure as you have passed a **list** length 2 of columns to **y**
- as simple a way as any is to override assigned color with `update_traces()`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1, 2, 4], 'y1': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'y2': [10, 9, 8, 7]})
fig = px.line(df, x='x', y=['y1', 'y2']).update_traces(line_color="black", showlegend=False)

fig
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Plotly [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/builtin-colorscales/) does not describe desired output, try avoiding `color` variable.

For instance:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp")
fig.show()
```

Gives this output:

[image: Output]